# I can't get the real name of the picture getClientOrginalName()

Tags: php, laravel

When the image is stored in the database, it is not saved by its real name
I need  help 
Please explain in detail where there is a mistake

```
public function store(Request $request){

    $headers = new headerslider;
    $headers->text = $request->input('text');
    $headers->imgName = $request->input('imgName');
    $headers->imgName = $request->file('imgName')->getClientOriginalName(); 

    if (request()->hasFile('imgName')) {
        $headers->imgName = request()->imgName->store('images', 'public', $headers);
    }
    $headers->save();

    return redirect('admin/index');
}
```

[image: look img id 17]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just use always like this

```
if ($headers->save()) {
     $imageOne  = $request->file('imgName');
     if($request->hasFile('imgName')){
            $imageOneUrl = $this->imageUpload($imageOne);
            $headers->imgName = $imageOneUrl;
     }

}


protected function imageUpload($imageOne){
    $fileNameWithExt   = $imageOne->getClientOriginalName();
    $mainContentPath   = $imageOne->storeAs('public/',$fileNameWithExt);
    return $fileNameWithExt;
}
```

It works fine for me till now

Comment: InvalidArgumentException
Disk [WhatsApp Image 2020-02-02 at 17.25.24.jpg] does not have a configured driver.